# Find function in React.JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am receiving a props data is look like

```
 data: [
    {
        rowNumber: 1,
        specification: null,
        validationMessage: [
            {
                isExists: true,
                errors: [
                    {
                        errorCode: "PredicateValidator",
                        errorMessage: "ERR: Length value is not in correct  "
                    },
                    {
                        errorCode: "PredicateValidator",
                        errorMessage: "Height Unit is not in correct  "
                    },
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        rowNumber: 2,
        specification: null,
        validationMessage: [
            {
                isExists: false,
                errors: []
            }
        ]
    },
]
```

In my render I have a button and I am trying to disable/ enable that button based on my errorMessage. If my eoorMessage contains a word "ERR:" I will disable the button otherwise it will be enabled.
Note: My errorMessage may be empty or may or may not have the word "Err:" word. If "ERR:" word exist any of my errorMessage I have to disable the button

I have tried this but it says x is not defined. How can I overcome this?

```
render() {

 const hasError = this.props.data ? this.props.data.find((x) => x.validationMessage.erros.find(z => z.errorMessage.indexof("ERR:"))) : ''
    return (
    <div>
        {(this.props.data) ?
            <div>

                (hasError) ?
                <Button variant="contained" className={classes.button} onClick={this.handleSave}>Continue</Button>
                :
                <Button variant="contained" disabled={true} className={classes.button} onClick={this.handleSave}>Continue</Button>

<Button variant="contained" className={classes.button} onClick={this.handleCancle}> Cancel</Button>
                </div>
                : ''}
        </div>
    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three problems in you code.

1. You are using `indexOf()` which will return `-1` if no element is found and its a trucy value. You should use `includes()`
2. You are using `find()` on `x.validationMessage.erros`. First add the missing `r` in `erros`. Secondly. You need to use `x.validationMessage[0].errors` because `validationMessage` is an array.
3. You are using `find()` on `data` which will return first occurrence if you want all disabled button you should use `filter()` otherwise `find()` is fine.

You question is bit unclear to me. I assumed to want to get all the items in which there is `"ERR:"`.
If you want to check that if any of them contain `err` or not use `.some()`

```js
let data = [
    {
        rowNumber: 1,
        specification: null,
        validationMessage: [
            {
                isExists: true,
                errors: [
                    {
                        errorCode: "PredicateValidator",
                        errorMessage: "ERR: Length value is not in correct  "
                    },
                    {
                        errorCode: "PredicateValidator",
                        errorMessage: "Height Unit is not in correct  "
                    },
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        rowNumber: 2,
        specification: null,
        validationMessage: [
            {
                isExists: false,
                errors: []
            }
        ]
    },
]


let newarr = data.filter(x=>x.validationMessage[0].errors.find(a=>a.errorMessage.includes('ERR:')))

let isError = data.some(x=>x.validationMessage[0].errors.find(a=>a.errorMessage.includes('ERR:')))

console.log(isError)

console.log(newarr)
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to fix the typo error like `validationMessage.erros` and `.indexof`.
Base on you data, `` should be `validationMessage.errors`, and `.indexof` should be `.indexOf`.

Secondly, you need to understand the indexOf. While your data `errorMessage: "ERR: ...` the expression `z.errorMessage.indexOf("ERR:"))` will return `0` which is evaluated to `false` in boolean.

To Fix this, you need to update it to `z.errorMessage.indexOf("ERR:") >=0` so that the hasError variable shall be:

```
const hasError = this.props.data ? this.props.data.find((x) => x.validationMessage.erros.find(z => z.errorMessage.indexof("ERR:") >= 0 )) : ''
```